# Tagged Sections

Tags: indexing

A professor I work with has loads of exam problems in LaTeX. However, he wants to index them in some sort. He wants to be able to tag them according to topic, last year it was used and so on, and then be able to sort and search them according to these tags.

The only answer I came up with was index and makeindex, however that seems a bit overkill. Is there any package that can accomplish this?

Comment: I'd put each exam problem in it's own file, then use some 3rd party system to track the rest of the stats. doing it in latex will be pretty difficult and will require lots of manual updates. Do you want to update the "last used" date every time you use a problem? Probably not.

Comment: As a professor who would like the very same thing, I have to agree with @Mica.  LaTeX is not a database.  You can put some of the metadata into the problem file with coded comments (or fancy macros) but sorting and tracking is not going to be easy.

Comment: I have to second @Mica and @Matthew Leingang for LaTeX suitability to this task. As said above, maybe you could add metadata in your sources (comments) to specify custom informations.

For sorting and searching: you can easily store these informations in a sqlite database using a simple python script, for example. No need for a parser module, simple regular expressions may suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Is there a way for this question to be closed?

Comment: @Mica: if you place your comment as an answer, then fabikw can accept it, and this question will go out of the 'unanswered' section.

Comment: @Mica: Can you please post your comment as an answer, as Taco suggested? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put each exam problem in it's own file, then use some 3rd party system to track the rest of the stats. doing it in latex will be pretty difficult and will require lots of manual updates. Do you want to update the "last used" date every time you use a problem? Probably not.